# Sending email with attachment in cakephp file real path

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am trying to send an email usingcake php here is the code

```
   $data =  "RSIMT7210;RSIMT7220";

        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $var = ROOT;
        $var = str_replace("api", "", $var);

        $attachments = array();

        $myArray = explode(';', $data);
        foreach($myArray as $sku)
        {                    
            $result = $this->Ring->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('sku'=>$sku)));
            $ring = $result['Ring'];

            $ringItems = explode(' ', $ring['name']);            
            $styleNumber = $ringItems[0];

            $mAttach = $var . "rings/" . "$styleNumber/image/white.jpg";                    
            $email->attachments($mAttach);                     
        }
```

But it seems to be adding one attachment only. Any way i can attach multiple files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the main problem was all the attachments were having same name. I had to put different names to make it to work. Now i am using this

```
$attachments[$styleNumber . ".jpg"] = array(
                                            'file' => $mAttach,
                                            'mimetype' => 'image/png',
                                            'contentId' => $styleNumber
                                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

the attachments() method allow you to add an array of image path. Change your source code like this

```
    $data =  "RSIMT7210;RSIMT7220";
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $var = ROOT;
    $var = str_replace("api", "", $var);

    $attachments = array();

    $myArray = explode(';', $data);
    foreach($myArray as $sku)
    {                    
        $result = $this->Ring->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('sku'=>$sku)));
        $ring = $result['Ring'];

        $ringItems = explode(' ', $ring['name']);            
        $styleNumber = $ringItems[0];

        $mAttach = $var . "rings/" . "$styleNumber/image/white.jpg"; 
        $attachments[] =  $mAttach;                          
    }
    $email->attachments($attachments);
```

Comment: `print_r()` your `$attachments` array and check the values cause the code seems ok.

Comment: @WayNe ["\/home\/thevowaa\/public_html\/brandstore\/rings\/DFWR0109\/image\/white.jpg","\/home\/thevowaa\/public_html\/brandstore\/rings\/DFWR6537\/image\/white.jpg"] this is the array